# TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null (when dm the bot)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Well, i have a problem.
The code works normal when i type in a channel, but when i dm the bot directly i get that console error...

is there a way to get arround ?

I did try to add .author but not working aswell

````
let guild = client.guilds.get(471XXXXXXXX4111);  
let membersWithRole = message.guild.roles.get(guild);
if(message.member.roles.some(r=>[config.Roles[1].Role1, "Mod", "Server Staff", "Proficient"].includes(r.name))) { 'SOME SHIT '});
} else {
  console.log(`Not authorized!!` + message.author.tag);
  message.channel.send(`U need to be an admin to preform this action`);
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before executing the command, you can check to see if the message was sent in a guild by using the boolean returned by [`Message.guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild), and return if it wasn't.

```js
if (!message.guild) return;
```

---

**Edit:**

If you want to continue with the command in DMs, you'll have to fetch the member within the desired guild.

```js
const guild = client.guilds.get('id');

const member = message.member || guild.members.get(message.author.id);
if (!member) return; // Check if the member isn't in the guild at all.

// Continue on with your code, using the 'member' variable.
```

Comment: Can i use both like people can ask trough pm an channel ?

Comment: Edited to accommodate your request.